# Why can natural logarithm receive negative $x$? (in the context of derivatives)

Tags: calculus, integration, logarithms

In our class we had this formula for $x<0$:
$$
\ln(-x)' = \frac{1}{-x} \cdot (-x)' = \frac{1}{x}
$$
The conclusion is that:
$$
\int\frac{1}{x}dx = \ln|x| + c, x \neq 0
$$

I don't understand how can $\ln$ receive negative numbers though?

Comment: If $x\lt0$ then $-x$ is a positive number.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It doesn't. The first formula is for negative $x$, this means that $-x$ is a positive number.

The second formula (the conclusion) is because the first we have that:

$$D\ln |x| = \begin{cases}
D\ln x = 1/x & \text{ if } x > 0\\
D\ln (-x) = 1/x & \text { if } x < 0\\
\end{cases}$$

where the second case is from the formula above, the first case is supposedly already known.

Comment: I think I got it now. But then we're talking about two different functions: one is $\ln x$ and the other one is $\ln|x|$ right?

Comment: No it's the same function.

Comment: But their domains are different no?

Comment: No, not really. The domain of the function $f(x) = \ln (-x)$ is different from $\ln$ and that's (ie $f$) a different function.

Comment: But $\ln|x|$ can receive negative $x$ while $\ln x$ can only receive positive $x$?

Comment: Yes, $g(x) = \ln|x|$ is also different from the function $\ln$. Basically $g$ is the composition of two functions, namely $\operatorname{abs}(y) = |y|$ and $\ln$, by composing with functions other than the identity map you get new functions different from both components.